# Value Error cannot index

Tags: python, int, literals, radix

```
text_file = ['Cats','Dogs','Frogs','(pass)', 'ants']
final_l = [[1], [2], [3], [5]]
final_dict = {'Dogs': [1], 'Cats': [1], 'Frogs': [1], 'ants': [1]}

for k, v in final_dict.items():
    for sl in final_l:
        for num in sl:
            if text_file[int(num)] == k:
                sl.append(k)
                sl.append(v)
print(final_l)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Luan/Desktop/1.py", line 9, in <module>
    if text_file[int(num)] == k:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Frogs'
```

So confused. Where is going wrong??? Why does it keep giving me this Value Error?? Why cannot I index?
I want to put it like this:

```
final_l = [[1, "Cats", [1]], [2, "Dogs", [1]], [3, "Frogs", [1]], [5, "ants", [1]]]
```

Comment: iterating through `sl` while modifying it at the same time, sounds a very good reason for errors similar to the one you posted, did u get my point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is you are iterating through a list while appending to it new values which will cause you errors and because also you happened to use the values you append to this list `sl` who are not right for indexing (like 'Frogs'), so my obvious suggestion would be to create a new list for that:

```
>>> new = []
>>> for k,v in final_dict.items():
    for i,sl in enumerate(final_l):
        for num in sl:
            if text_file[num-1] == k:
                new.append(sl+[k,v])


>>> new
[[3, 'Frogs', [1]], [5, 'ants', [1]], [2, 'Dogs', [1]], [1, 'Cats', [1]]]
```

Please note, that list indexing starts from 0.

Comment: You are right. Thanks! I think this is the most understandable way

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused because text_file is a list and you have to pass an integer in to reference and index of that list. You are passing num which is iterating a list that is being changed as you operate on it. When you append 'Frongs' and '[1]' to the list, num iterates over those values then you try to reference the index 'Frogs' of text_file. That causes a value error.

You can use:

```
import copy
for num in copy.copy(sl):
```

as one possible solution, though I am pretty confused as to what your final objective is.

Comment: sorry.. I'm trying to get  a list like this: [[1, "Cats", [1]], [2, "Dogs", [1]], [3, "Frogs", [1]], [5, "ants", [1]]]